# Get Text from selected value of a selectbox

Tags: javascript, php

Profile Page:

Users update their information:

- Name
- Site URL
- Country
- Biography

Country is a select field that gets the option values and inserts it into the database, I also have a code that gets the selected TEXT and inserts that into the database.

col_country_code & col_country_name

This works fine when the selectbox is always being selected.

```
echo "<select name='$select_name' id='$select_name' onchange='document.getElementById(\"location_content\").value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text'>";
```

This adds the selected option values TEXT into a hidden input. BUT it only works onchange...

What if a user only wants to update their Biography? Problem is, its not sending the option values TEXT because there is no onchange event!

How do I solve this problem? Right now if a user wants to update his/her profile they need to select their country every time? I dont want this...

Comment: You should show previous country selected when user is in a edit mode

Comment: fetch country from db and display on page thats it .

Comment: I can't, Im displaying a image flag corresponding to the country code, eg: us = us.png wich displays Location: us.png United States... this is why I need both.

Comment: Why don't you keep a button named 'update', and once the user has made all the necessary changes, they click on the button and it gets updated? Why particularly on change of the select box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, what you should do is that, on page load you have to set the `<select>` value to a value already in DB, so that on save, if the user does not change the `<select>`, the value which was saved to DB gets saved, if changed, then the changed value gets saved.

something like this:

```
$selectValue = getCountry(); // this gets the information of the user from DB

echo "<select name='$select_name' id='$select_name' onchange='document.getElementById(\"location_content\").value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].text' value='$selectValue'>";
```

Note that I have added a new attribute (value)

Comment: My apologies... This did indeed work, I had a typo! Accepted answer.